# requesting for a declined facebook permission again without popping up the facebook dialog twice

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

What is the proper way to re-ask for previously denied Facebook permission?

Say an application asks for a read permission like `user_photos`.
The user rejects this for task A.

They proceed to use the app but come across task B which requires the same permission `user_photos`, but this time the user is willing to provide the Facebook permission.

Given this behavior, I ask the user *again* for this permission, and with the Android Facebook SDK, this is done using the `requestNewReadPermissions` API:

```
  session.requestNewReadPermissions(
    new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this,PERMISSION_USER_PHOTOS));
```

However, this call however only seems to work **after** a Facebook session has been opened *(e.g. in the `Session.StatusCallback`)* like so:

```
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception e) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {
        if (session.getDeclinedPermissions().contains("user_photos")) {
            session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this,
            "user_photos"));
            return;
        }
        // ...
    } else if (session.isClosed()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Since this permission was already asked and denied earlier, the first-time we open the Facebook session with the required permission, like so:

```
if (session != null && !session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
        .setPermissions(PERMISSION_USER_PHOTOS)
        .setCallback(this));
}
```

Facebook throws up a spinner and a native dialog, but immediately returns back (without showing the permissions window to the user), saying permission was declined (because this was not considered to be a "re-request").

Then it proceeds to the session status callback where, *(as shown in the previous code snippet)*, I check if the permission was declined, and request a new read permission.
It throws up a spinner again with the FB native dialog, but now finally shows the native permissions FB permissions window, giving the user a choice to either accept/decline again.

My questions:

1. If I know the permission was already declined once, is it possible
   to open the session with a "new" read permission?  I cannot find a
   way to open a Facebook session in any of the variants of
   `session.openForRead()` with this "new permissions" flag.
2. If 1. is not possible, is there a way I can avoid the whole dance
   of:
    spinner ↣ popup *(but immediate return)* ↣ spinner ↣ show
   re-request popup

I'm not using a the "Facebook button" but rather the custom UI method as recommended in the FB docs.
Specifically I'm using a fragment with the `UiLifecycleHelper` to manage my Facebook lifecycle calls.
Here's the code to my  FB lifecycle fragment (if that's relevant to solving the problem):

```
public abstract class FacebookLifecycleFragment
  extends BaseFragment
  implements Session.StatusCallback {

    private UiLifecycleHelper _uiLifecycleHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        _uiLifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), this);
        _uiLifecycleHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        _uiLifecycleHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        _uiLifecycleHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        _uiLifecycleHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        _uiLifecycleHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        _uiLifecycleHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

I accordingly have `LoginFbFragment`, `PublishFbPhotoFragment` etc. fragments that perform the "permission request + required action on Facebook" calls on their start (or a trigger of a button on that fragment).

Comment: what if you make a new session if user decline your permission?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira : creating a new session seems to follows the same behavior.

Comment: reasons for downvote :S ?

Comment: @KaushikGopal Did you find a solution?